# Calling New-PSSession from ASP.NET app fails (creates null object)

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I've got a powershell script that I'm trying to run on a remote computer. I have a local PS script that creates a session to the remote machine and then calls the remote script, like this:

```
param($serverName, $rootPath, $appsToInstall)
$session = Enter-PsSession -ComputerName $serverName

$command = {
param($path,$apps) 
$path\temp\IISsetup.ps1 $path $apps
}

$output = Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock $command -ArgumentList 
   $rootPath,$appsToInstall

Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

If I run the local script from a PS console, it works just as expected, and the remote script runs. However, when I try to execute it from my ASP.NET app, the $session variable is null -- a session is not created/established--and, therefore, the script is not run on the remote computer. Powershell does not return an error or any other indication that it failed...I can just see that `$session -eq $null`.

I've verified that the apppool that the web app is using is running under the same account that I log on with, so it *should* have the same permissions.
Here's how I'm calling the local script from within ASP.NET:

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                {
                    remoteRunspace.Open();
                    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        ps.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

                        var cmd = new Command(Path.Combine(ServerPath, "LocalIISSetupLauncher.ps1"));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("serverName", this.Server.ServerName);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("rootPath", LocalIisDirectory);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("appsToInstall", Server.InstalledApplications.ToList().ToArray());

                        ps.Commands.AddCommand(cmd);

                        var results = ps.Invoke();
```

I'm hoping someone can see what I'm missing; the Googles don't seem to have much on powershell failing to create a remote session.

Comment: I haven't got an answer but I'd recommend looking at the config of your IIS. I think you'll need the website to be configured for anon access\no impersonation to avoid any double hop issues.

Comment: "$session = Enter-PsSession -ComputerName $serverName" doesn't make sense - shouldn't that be $session = new-pssession?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand there can be two problems :

1. `Enter-PsSession` is used for interactive remote session you'd better consider to replace it with `New-PSSession`.
2. You may encounter credential troubles

Whatever [Using PowerShell 2.0 from ASP.NET Part 1](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html) seems to be a good cookbook for what you want to do.Exists three older ones [Part1](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2008/05/powershell-and-aspnet.html), [Part2](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2008/05/powershell-and-aspnet-part-2.html) [Part3](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2008/05/powershell-and-aspnet-part-3.html).

Comment: You're link to "Using PowerShell 2.0 from ASP.NET Part 1" seems to be bad.